# Google Translate,alternatives to translation

Tags: api, google-translate, machine-translation

when i'm using the google-translate website like this 
https://translate.google.de/#de/en/schnell
i have the possibility to click on the suggested translation, and i can see alternatives (for example quick, fast etc.)

Is there any possiblity to get these alternatives via the API ? Or does anybody know a reliable API to get a translation for a single word with alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no such feature. I've filed a Feature Request to get this implemented, although there is no ETA.